# Program stops execution if window loses focus. Why?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am running a big python script on a `bash` terminal. The problem is that everytime I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or click outside the terminal into another windows (Say, google-chrome), the program stops execution. 
 Then I need to put the terminal back in focus by clicking inside it to resume execution. 
This keeps happening all the time. 

What could be wrong?

Comment: This question might belong on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: I have the same problem. Any updates on this? Sadly there is not much else that a web search returned.

Comment: Same here. I did some tests and it seems somehow related to buffering, since when outputting short lines I find it harder to reproduce it than when outputting long lines. Also, it does not seem to be deterministic: sometimes when clicking to lose focus, the process halts, sometimes not. Setting the window as "Always on top" also prevents the process from halting at all.

Comment: Just some additional information: this happens on both gnome-terminal and on the xfce terminal emulator (I'm running xfce). I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior on xterm neither on konsole. Could it be a bug?